# can't find downloaded laravel files in mapped homestead folder

Tags: laravel, homestead

i just set up homestead and made sure that my folder is mapped correctly( by displaying some php content ), but when i download laravel from the virtual machine i can't find the files in the mapped folder.

homestead.yaml :

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/neo/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: fresh.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/fresh/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - fresh
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.10       fresh.app
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your laravel homestead is in your home root's directory. Also
Change your

`- map: C:/Users/neo/Code`

to

`- map: /Users/neo/Code`

Then in your Homestead environment run command:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

It should work fine now and map your folder.

Comment: thanks for commenting.
with "Make sure your laravel homestead is in your home root's directory" you mean that the homestead directory must be in c:/users/{user_name}/ ?
i tred your instructions but didn't work aswell

Comment: I'm using unix. I mean it because i configured several vagrant box in different directories and the only vagrant configuration who mapped my folders correctly was the one who was in the home root's directory http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165771/root-home-directory-vs-tilde .

Comment: i tried that but it didn't workout for me so i downloaded laravel where i tried to echo some php (not in the virtual machine) and it is working for me, i hope i don't face problems in the future because of that because if i'll have to use commands in the virtual machine they won't affect the files.